# Minecraft 1.10 Custom GameRules?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was fooling around with gamerules, when I noticed this:

[image]

I guess I added a gamerule to the list?  I'd like to know more about this and how it can be used.

Thanks!

Comment: This no longer workd in 1.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Gamerules makes you add other rules. This is an example:

> Enable/Disable every zombie being a baby
>
> /gamerule onlyBabyZombies 1/0
>
> http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/redstone-creations/2352873-buffed-mobs-45-gamerule-options

That is one of the custom gamerules. Tutorial on how to make a custom gamerule: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2353772-tutorial-make-your-own-custom-gamerules