# How to create and use custom gamerules?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Recently, there were a few posts about creating custom gamerules, but no question or answer covered the creation and usage of custom gamerules. [This post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283621/minecraft-1-10-custom-gamerules/283627#283627) tries to uncover this, but it's just a link-only answer to a tutorial I didn't understand.

From version 1.9 (or maybe earlier), you can create custom gamerules, eg.

```
/gamerule customGamerule false
```

This will create a gamerule named customGamerule, currently set to false. It can be changed to true and Bach, but without effect. **How can one add an *effect* to a custom gamerule?**

Comment: Custom GameRules no longer exist in 1.13

Comment: @ppperry Oh. I guess one can still use a series of scoreboard commands to have the same result. Did those change in 1.13?

Comment: The syntax of `/scoreboard` changed in a few ways in 1.13, and some of it was split into new commands, but the core functionality remained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to detect the value of any gamerule (both default and custom), CommandStats must be used, which will set the value of the gamerule as a score. Only the `QueryResult` trigger will be provided with a return value when running `/gamerule <name>`.

## Prerequisites

Objective to hold the value.

```
/scoreboard objectives add Gamerules dummy
```

The target of CommandStats must be tracked in the objective in order to obtain the return value. In this case, a fake player named "$customGamerule" will be used to hold the value.

```
/scoreboard players set $customGamerule Gamerules 0
```

You can set the custom gamerule's value to any numerical value for detection. If you set it to "true" or "false", it will be interpreted as 1 and 0 respectively. If you set it to any other string, it will be 0.

```
/gamerule customGamerule 0
/gamerule customGamerule 1
/gamerule customGamerule 100
/gamerule customGamerule true
```

## Detection

[image: Repeating > Chain > Conditional Chain]

1. Stand on top of the command block and run the following yourself.

   ```
   /stats block ~ ~-1 ~ set QueryResult $customGamerule Gamerules
   ```

   Now every time the command block executes a command that provides a `QueryResult` return value, fake player "$customGamerule" will have their "Gamerules" score set equal to that value.

   The command that will be placed within that command block, which queries the value of the gamerule:

   ```
   /gamerule customGamerule
   ```
2. In order to detect the fake player's value, `/scoreboard players test` must be used.

   ```
   /scoreboard players test $customGamerule Gamerules 1 1
   ```
3. **Conditional.** Command to run if the "customGamerule" gamerule is set to 1.

   ```
   /say "customGamerule" is set to 1.
   ```

As long as the gamerule is set to "1" or "true", the `/say` command will execute.